# Setting custom action bar view in theme

Tags: android

Is there a way to define a custom action bar view in the theme instead of setting it in every activity?  Currently I have this code in onCreate for every activity I have:

```
    View actionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_title, null);     
    getActionBar().setCustomView(actionBar);
```

Comment: Create a base Activity class and put it in its onCreate method. Now extend that base class instead of Activity.

Comment: @Ahmad is right. I almost clicked "Post your answer" but Ahmad beat me to it by 6 seconds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom view can be defined in the style of the action bar:

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">     
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/action_bar_title</item>
</style>
```